# PHP - How to limit request from chrome extension only?

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension on Chrome, which makes a request to my PHP page. I don't know how to make the page only serve request from the Chrome extension only, to make sure that my resource is not abused by unexpected clients, like robot

Answer (score 3):

When your extension makes the request, include a unique field that you can retrieve on the server to verify that the request is legitimate (like an API key).

Make the request to *http://yoursite.com/yourscript.php?apikey=123456789*

Check the request in your script

```
<?php

$api_key = "123456789";

if ((!isset($_GET[apikey])) or (strcmp($api_key, $_GET['apikey']) !== 0)) { header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden'); die(); } // Invalid request
else {
    // Valid request
}

?>
```

Edit: It's worth noting that using this method it's entirely possible for someone to sniff the location of your script and your API code and make calls to it manually, but for the purposes of robots and random viewers this method is fine.

Comment: It would be more polite to actually answer with a 403.

Comment: @Xan I overlooked that, edited! Cheers.

Comment: Hi @pablo, I thought about this also, but, as you mentioned it's incomplete security, I hope to get advice for a more secure way. The robot I mentioned here is written by someone purposely to abuse my service, he surely can overcome the api-key. Thanks

Comment: @Ben There will be no complete security here if they're able to get the extension. Any skilled attacker can bypass your restrictions.